# Magento 1.9.1 500 Memory exhausted error, clearing client session help

Tags: magento-1.9, http-error-500, memory-leak

The exhausted memory error appears regardless of the memory limit for certain random clients. Setting 2, 4, 8GB of memory limit not resolve the problem. The error appears in each case. Client navigate the site and at some point he saw 500 memory limit error. Increasing the limit does not help. I found out that if I delete the session for that client from the DB, the 500 error disappears for him. 
Thank You.
In my case the last error appeared in:

```
Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 683

$buyRequest = new Varien_Object(unserialize($option->getValue()));
```

Here is request, but I still don't know what is the reason.

```
Array([0] => SELECT `main_table`.*, `default_value_title`.`title` AS `default_title`, `store_value_title`.`title` AS `store_title`, IF(store_value_title.title IS NULL, default_value_title.title, store_value_title.title) AS `title`, `default_value_price`.`price` AS `default_price`, `default_value_price`.`price_type` AS `default_price_type`, `store_value_price`.`price` AS `store_price`, `store_value_price`.`price_type` AS `store_price_type`, IF(store_value_price.price IS NULL, default_value_price.price, store_value_price.price) AS `price`, IF(store_value_price.price_type IS NULL, default_value_price.price_type, store_value_price.price_type) AS `price_type` FROM `catalog_product_option_type_value` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_title` AS `default_value_title` ON default_value_title.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_title` AS `store_value_title` ON store_value_title.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND store_value_title.store_id = '1' LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` AS `default_value_price` ON default_value_price.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND default_value_price.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` AS `store_value_price` ON store_value_price.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND store_value_price.store_id = '1' WHERE (default_value_title.store_id = 0) AND (`option_id` IN('167747', '167748', '167749', '167750')) ORDER BY sort_order ASC, title ASC
[1] => Array
    (
        [form_key] => jncsjdhbvdjfhvb
        [product] => 143426
        [related_product] => 
        [super_attribute] => Array
            (
                [237] => 311
            )

        [options] => Array
            (
                [167748] => 1855652
                [167749] => 1855654
                [167750] => 1855660
                [167747] => 1855644
            )

        [qty] => 4
        [isAjax] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
        [HOSTNAME] => 
        [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
        [REQUEST_URI] => /checkout/cart/add/uenc/jncsjdhbvdjfhvbreplace=/product/143426/form_key/jncsjdhbvdjfhvb/
        [QUERY_STRING] => 
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
        [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
        [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
        [REDIRECT_URL] => /checkout/cart/add/uenc/jncsjdhbvdjfhvbreplace=/product/143426/form_key/jncsjdhbvdjfhvb/
        [REMOTE_PORT] => 13549
        [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
        [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
        [SERVER_PORT] => 443
        [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
        [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

        [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
        [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
        [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
        [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
        [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
        [HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/json, text/javascript; q=0.01
        [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 213
        [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
        [REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
        [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
        [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
        [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1545059133.8192
        [REQUEST_TIME] => 1545059133
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [type] => 1
        [message] => Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
        [file] => /lib/Varien/Object.php
        [line] => 270
    )
```